# Establecer un estilo a varias ventanas al seleccionar un checkbox y guardar la preferencia en javaFx

Tags: css, javafx

Soy principiante en java y estoy creando una aplicación que contiene dos ventanas, cada una con su respectivo controlador. La primera ventana es el menú principal que contiene un checkbox, la otra ventana contiene un TableView y un TextField. A estas dos ventanas les creé una hoja de estilos, que contiene, en su mayoría, colores blancos. Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo es posible establecer, por ejemplo, un modo oscuro (con una hoja de estilo previamente creado) a estas ventanas, con tan solo seleccionar el checkbox del menú principal?.
Estaba pensando en obtener el evento del checkbox, pero no se como. En conjunto a esto, quisiera saber como guardar la configuración que el usuario seleccione, por ejemplo, si el usuario establece el modo oscuro, que al momento de que cierre y vuelva abrir la aplicación, se inicialice con la configuracion que selecciono, en este caso, el modo oscuro.

PD: ¿Qué tema debería estudiar para saber esto?.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me parece que vas bien encaminado, puedes guardarlo en `Preferences` y leer los datos cuando la aplicación de abre. [Aquí tienes un tutorial completo sobre preferencias](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPreferences/article.html). Intenta tu código y cuando haya un problema entonces plantéalo en una pregunta. Stackoverflow es para resolver problemas concretos, por ejemplo, algo que no funciona en un determinado código.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!